# why std::abs output is incorrect on MSVC2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am having incorrect results from std::abs with MSVC and GCC

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

int main()
{
  std::cerr << std::sqrt((-6.)*(-6.) + 288.*288.) << "\n";
  std::cerr << std::abs( std::complex<float>(-6, 288) ) << std::endl;

  return 0L;
}
```

The above code produces different results on VC++ (MSVS 2015 CE with updates) and gcc 4.9.2

With MSVC

```
288.062
288.063
```

With GCC

```
288.062
288.062
```

Now the actual result is 288.062 which is correct on gcc with std::abs and std::sqrt. But msvc has different results when using std::sqrt and std::abs which can be a bug in msvc2015.

But looking at code of xcomplex, I don't understand the implementation of _Fabs(). Could someone help me understand this specific code and a possible analysis of how the code ended with such a bug.

Comment: Note that in the first line you are using doubles.

Comment: Did you really expect that all of this floating point manipulation would yield the exact same results for two differing compilers, given that floating point is an approximation?  I wouldn't be surprised if you got different results from using the same compiler, but changed some compiler options (like optimizations or some other setting).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*"Now the actual result is 288.062 [...]."* - The actual result is `288.06249...`, or something like that, which cannot be represented exactly by a `float` or a `double`.

Both compiler actually returns the same value, you can check by printing more digits:

```
double re = -6, im = 288;
std::cout << "sqrt: " << '\n'
          << std::setprecision(6) << std::sqrt(re * re + im * im) << '\n'
          << std::setprecision(30) << std::sqrt(re * re + im * im) << '\n';
std::cout << "abs:  " << '\n'
          << std::setprecision(6) << std::abs(std::complex<float>(im, re)) << '\n'
          << std::setprecision(30) << std::abs(std::complex<float>(im, re)) << '\n';
```

Output (with both VC 19.0 and GCC 4.9.3):

```
sqrt: 
288.062
288.062493219787313591950805858
abs:  
288.062
288.0625
```

Both compiler actually return `288.0625` for `std::abs`<sup>1</sup>, but GCC output `288.62` (floor) and VC `288.063` (ceil) - This is not a "problem" in `std::abs`, but a "problem" in the way output is formatted<sup>2</sup>.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Both compilers return a less approximated value with `std::abs` because you are using `float` for `std::abs` while you are using `double` with `std::sqrt`. Replace `6.` and `288.` by `6.f` and `288.f` or `std::complex<float>` by `std::complex<double>` and you will get the same result with `std::sqrt` and `std::abs`.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> As far as I know, the standard does not define a way of rounding floating point value when using `std::ostream`, the actual specifications comes from `printf` format conversion `%f` which only *recommend* a way of rounding (which is, I think, the way gcc round using "round half to even").</sub>

Comment: ^1 or change to `std::complex<double>(-6, 288)`